# Handle first promise first, the rest in order of completion

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I need to fetch data from multiple APIs, all of them are pretty slow to return data.

The first API returns base data. This information is not required to call the other APIs, but it is required to process their results. So while I can send out all requests in parallel, I **need** to process the results of the first request first.

For example, request nr 1 returns after 30 seconds, nr 2 returns after 15 seconds, and nr 3 returns after 60 seconds. This means that after 30 seconds I can process the results of both nr 1 and 2, and after 60 seconds I can process nr 3. I would prefer to be able to process the base information as soon as possible to provide feedback to the user.

How would I do this in JavaScript?

I can use Promise.all to wait with processing until **all** fetches have completed, but this can potentially take a long time for any result to show. (In my example, 60 seconds.) I can also launch the first fetch by itself and use Promise.all for the rest after the first reply is processed, but that will mean everything else is delayed by the first request (ie, 30 seconds).

I have a feeling the solution is in using async/await, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: try [js async](https://javascript.info/async)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for multiple `Promise.all` calls, each with the base request and one of the other requests.

```
const base = baseRequest().then(preprocess);
Promise.all([
  Promise.all([base, firstRequest()]).then(([baseData, firstData]) => processFirst(baseData, firstData)),
  Promise.all([base, secondRequest()]).then(([baseData, secondData]) => processSecond(baseData, secondData)),
  Promise.all([base, thirdRequest()]).then(([baseData, thirdData]) => processThird(baseData, thirdData)),
  …
]).catch(err => {
  // handle (first) error from any of the above
})
```

<sub>(you can also add individual error handling as you see fit)</sub>

This will fire off all requests at the same time, and call `processFirst` / `processSecond` / `processThird` as soon as the data they require respectively is available. The outer `Promise.all` will fulfill once all processing is done, you can chain something onto that as well.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of putting the base request in a variable, very nice and clear solution! One question, is there any reason for the outer `Promise.all` instead of just running the inner promises after eachother?

Comment: @Peter Joined error handling. You don't want this to crash your application with an unhandled promise rejection :-)

Comment: Good point, though I would probably want to treat only errors on the base data as fatal errors, and handle the others with a notification only. Having the outer Promise.all means all requests are abandoned when only one fails, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Nothing is abandoned, the individual promises do not affect each other. Each request has its own handlers and will always execute those, even if the `Promise.all(…)` promise was already rejected for some reason. Basically it's useful if you want to show a *single* "something has failed" notification, not one notification per error. Or if you want to show an "everything is loaded and processed" notification after all requests have finished.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this fairly simply with a couple of `Promise.all` calls (as you suspect) combined with one explicit promise callback. It depends partially on when you want to process the "other" results.

#### If you want to process "base" ASAP but the "other" results only after they've all arrived

...it would look something like this:

```
async function doTheWork() {
    const [processedBaseResult, otherResults] = await Promise.all([
        baseQuery().then(rawBaseResult => processBase(rawBaseResult)),
        Promise.all([
            otherQuery(1),
            otherQuery(2),
            otherQuery(3),
        ])
    ]);
    // ...process `otherResults` here, using `processedBaseResult`...
    return otherResults.map(otherRaw => processOther(processedBaseResult, otherRaw));
}
```

That starts all of the work in parallel, handles the base result as soon as it's available (via the `.then` callback), and waits until everything is done. When everything is done, you can use the processed base results to process the other results.

```js
const rnd = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
const baseQuery = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, rnd(), "base result"));
const otherQuery = (value) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, rnd(), `other result #${value}`));
const processBase = (raw) => raw + " processed";
const processOther = (baseProcessed, otherRaw) => baseProcessed + ": " + otherRaw
async function doTheWork() {
    const [processedBaseResult, otherResults] = await Promise.all([
        baseQuery().then(rawBaseResult => processBase(rawBaseResult)),
        Promise.all([
            otherQuery(1),
            otherQuery(2),
            otherQuery(3),
        ])
    ]);
    // ...process `otherResults` here, using `processedBaseResult`...
    return otherResults.map(otherRaw => processOther(processedBaseResult, otherRaw));
}
doTheWork().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

#### If you want to process "base" ASAP *and* process "other" results ASAP as well

...that would look something like this:

```
async function processOther(basePromise, otherPromise) {
    const [baseResult, otherRaw] = await Promise.all([basePromise, otherPromise]);
    return baseResult + ": " + otherRaw;
}

async function doTheWork() {
    const basePromise = baseQuery().then(rawBaseResult => processBase(rawBaseResult));
    const otherResults = await Promise.all([
        processOther(basePromise, otherQuery(1)),
        processOther(basePromise, otherQuery(2)),
        processOther(basePromise, otherQuery(3)),
    ]);
    return otherResults;
}
```

That allows you to start processing each "other" result as soon as possible, waiting for the overall process to complete. Note that although we `await` `basePromise` more than once, that's absolutely fine; all of those will get the same fulfillment value.

```js
const rnd = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
const baseQuery = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, rnd(), "base result"));
const otherQuery = (value) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, rnd(), `other result #${value}`));
const processBase = (raw) => raw + " processed";
async function processOther(basePromise, otherPromise) {
    const [baseResult, otherRaw] = await Promise.all([basePromise, otherPromise]);
    return baseResult + ": " + otherRaw;
}

async function doTheWork() {
    const basePromise = baseQuery().then(rawBaseResult => processBase(rawBaseResult));
    const otherResults = await Promise.all([
        processOther(basePromise, otherQuery(1)),
        processOther(basePromise, otherQuery(2)),
        processOther(basePromise, otherQuery(3)),
    ]);
    return otherResults;
}
doTheWork().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```js
const timeOutPromise = (data, time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), time))


const promise1 = timeOutPromise("first api data", 3000);

const promise2 = timeOutPromise("second api data", 1500);

const promise3 = timeOutPromise("third api data", 5000);


promise1.then(d => console.log(d))


promise2.then(d => {
 console.log(d)
 promise1.then(d => {
   console.log("promise 1 and 2 resolved")
 })
})

promise3.then(d => {
 console.log(d)
 promise1.then(d => {
   console.log("promise 1 and 3 resolved")
 })
})
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand. At the moment you write `promise 1 and (2/3) resolved`, you only have access to the return data of promise 1!

Comment: you're right! but it was just a proof of concept you just have to assign a different variable name to the result